# Script para Ordenar Datos

Tags: php, javascript

Soy programador pero me especializo en PHP. Tengo una serie de links que llevan a unas fotos de un contenido que debo llevar a una página. Esos Links estan identificados con un código por ejemplo:

```
https://example.com/18-57475.jpg
```

Debo emparejar esos links con su contenido correspondiente en una Hoja Excel. O sea, en la Hoja Excel estan esos códigos que señale arriba, pero necesito un script que identifique ese codigo en la Hoja Excel y luego mueva el link de con su respectivo código.

Si no me entienden puedo dar explicaciones mas claras.

Comment: Si buscas un script para ordenar datos, las etiquetas [tag:c#], [tag:c++] y [tag:c] sobran, ya que son lenguajes compilados no interpretados.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta. Tu pregunta es por un  lado demasiado amplia para el formato del sitio, y por otro deberías centrarte en un lenguaje de programación concreto. Un saludo

Comment: ¿Has investigado / intentado algo? ¿Qué dificultad tienes en base a esa primer intento? No podemos resolver el problema por ti, sino ayudarte a resolverlo. Saludos.